# Avoiding typing fully qualified name

Tags: c#, class, code-readability

Let's say I have an helper class, like so:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class DataHelpers
    {
        public string SysnamePath ( string db , string schema , string table )
        {
            return "[" + db + "].[" + schema + "].[" + table + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite this or what can I do to make it so that I don't have to keep typing the fully qualified name...

```
string dbpath = DataHelpers.SysnamePath(...);
```

I don't want it to be an extension method or I don't understand how that could help and I don't want to paste the method in the same page as the caller.

It's possible that I don't understand something basic, as I am teaching myself.  My understanding is that the method has to be in a class.  I just don't want to type that class name very time.

Like I said, I'm sure this is something basic.

Comment: Usually helper methods are `static`, which means you don't have to instantiate a class in order to use them (like `Console.WriteLine()`). Aside from that, it's been my experience that most developers write out the class name rather than hiding it with a `using` statement. Presumably for more readable / understandable code. It also becomes necessary when you eventually have some other `Helpers` class that also has a `SysnamePath` method, because at that point you're going to have to do some extra typing to differentiate them.

Comment: @Rufus, thank you so much.  I have heard the term, "helper class" used, but I've been referring to my static extension methods as extension methods and the methods I use to reduce keystrokes as "helper classes."  I will have to look that up.  This could easily be a static method (if I make the class static too) though, right?

Comment: @RufusL Nevermind, my question was answered in by the answer below.

Comment: The method can be static either way. For example, the `string` class is not static, but it has static methods, such as `Compare`, `Concat`, `Format`, etc. The class can also be made static if it contains only static methods and properties.

Comment: Oh wow. Ok, I thought that since static classes can contain only static methods that static methods had to be in static classes.  This is a mind blowing moment.  I don't need these all separated in my class library now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your class and method static:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class DataHelpers
    {
        public static string SysnamePath ( string db , string schema , string table )
        {
            return "[ " + db + " ].[ " + schema + " ].[ " + table + " ]";
        }
    }
}
```

add in the header of file, where you want to use it:

```
using static DataHelpers;
```

use:

```
string dbpath = SysnamePath(...);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)

Comment: Duh!  Of course!  In situations where the method can't be static due to the class modifier, I'll try adding to the namespace declaration, but this is the answer I was looking for!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In your namespace add:

```
using DH = MyNamespace.DataHelpers
```

Then you can do:

```
var p = new DH();
```

Comment: I'm actually loving this because it reduces keystrokes when I'm using a method constantly.